# How do you refresh html after updating algolia data?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, algolia

I am currently using Firestore to store user data and am mirroring it in Algolia for search functionality. I have the following HTML code displaying all the data in my Algolia index:

```
<ais-instantsearch [config] = "searchConfig">

  <ais-search-box (change)="searchChanged($event)"></ais-search-box>

  <ais-hits *ngIf="showResults">

    <ng-template let-hits="hits">

      <ion-list>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let hit of hits" [routerLink]="['/tabs/home/details', hit.objectId]">
            <ais-highlight attribute="title" [hit]="hit"></ais-highlight>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ng-template>

  </ais-hits>

</ais-instantsearch>
```

But the problem is that after I go and create a new entry and add it to my Firestore database (which Algolia then mirrors automatically), it doesn't update in the html above. If I search for it in the search box, the new entry appears fine, however, it doesn't appear in my list of data entries being displayed on the page.

I've tried the ionic refresh function (as shown below) and I've tried adding location.reload() to it, but this brings me back to the index page for my app, not the current one. Any ideas how to reload my list to reflect the latest changes in my Algolia database?

Here is the TS:

```
doRefresh(event) {
  console.log('Begin async operation');

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Async operation has ended');
  this.changeRef.detectChanges();
  event.target.complete();
  }, 2000);
}

showResults = true;
```

Comment: how do you get the hits array?

Comment: ais-hits is built-in with Algolia instantsearch and it retrieves from the database